# Still getting python module "ImportError" message

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to run a module called MAVProxy that sets up a connection between my computer (Windows 7) and a quadcopter.  I am new to this, so any help is appreciated.  I have looked around for similar problems (there are many) but no solution that has been offered has helped me yet.

The PATH in Environment Variables has been updated to be: `C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts\;C:\Users\...\Downloads\Mav`.

A command prompt has been opened, cd to directory where mavproxy.py is at, then I try to run the module by typing: `python mavproxy.py --master=COM5`

And I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "mavproxy.py", line 20, in <module>
    from MAVProxy.modules.lib import textconsole
    ImportError: No module named MAVProxy.modules.lib
```

Here is the file structure of the associated files:
`C:\Users\...\Downloads\Mav\MAVProxy\MAVProxy\mavproxy.py`

And here is the beginning code of mavproxy.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
mavproxy - a MAVLink proxy program

Copyright Andrew Tridgell 2011
Released under the GNU GPL version 3 or later

'''

import sys, os, struct, math, time, socket
import fnmatch, errno, threading
import serial, Queue, select

import select

# allow running without installing
#sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), '..'))


from MAVProxy.modules.lib import textconsole
from MAVProxy.modules.lib import mp_settings

class MPSettings(object):
    def __init__(self):
```

I appreciate any help with this,

Thanks.

Comment: Do the files `...\Mav\MAXProxy\MAVProxy\__init__.py`, `...\Mav\MAXProxy\MAVProxy\modules\__init__.py`, `...\Mav\MAXProxy\MAVProxy\modules\lib\__init__.py` exist?

Comment: Yes they do.  Here are the files associated with [MAVProxy](https://github.com/tridge/MAVProxy)

and [mavlink-1.0.9](https://github.com/mavlink/mavlink/downloads)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have your MAVProxy in your PYTHONPATH (or whatever is equivalent on Windows)?